# Grub Rescue Error while boot windows 7 laptop

Tags: grubrescue, reboot

I have an old Vaio E-series laptop. When I start the laptop, it shows grub rescue error. I have almost everything mentioned related to this error on the internet. I went to the extent of even erasing the entire hard disk with DBAN but even that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any other advice as a last try?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You would need Linux installed to properly configure grub.  When you install Ubuntu grub will install a default configuration that will include all your Windows and Linux OSes that are installed.

If you don't have any installed (as per your reference to having reformatted the drive) the boot can't continue.

If you're having problems installing Ubuntu on your freshly formatted drive, we can try to identify this problem after you boot to the install disk.

If it's Windows 7 that you are trying to install you a forum relating to Windows such as http://superuser.com can walk you thought those steps, which should be basically the same... boot to the Windows Install disk and proceed from there.  Windows will install a different boot manager from Grub.